# :couchbeam.save_doc/2 in Elixir

Tags: couchdb, elixir

Written some code to save a document to CouchDB in [Elixir](http://elixir-lang.org/) using [Couchbeam](https://github.com/benoitc/couchbeam):

```
case :couchbeam.open_or_create_db(server, "database", []) do
  { :ok, db } ->
    doc = [
      _id: "auth_#{username}",
      content: 'some text'
    ]

    case :couchbeam.save_doc(db, doc) do
      { :ok, saved_doc } -> saved_doc
      { :error, :econnrefused } -> %{
        :error_code => "save_error",
        :error => "Failure to create account"
      }
    end
  { :error, :econnrefused } ->
    IO.puts "Could not connect to server"
end
```

This results in an error stating that **save_doc/4** is not a matching function clause, when it is clearly defined in my local couchbeam.erl.

**save_doc/4** is defined as:

```
-spec save_doc(Db::db(), doc(), mp_attachments(), Options::list()) ->
    {ok, doc()} | {error, term()}.
save_doc(#db{server=Server, options=Opts}=Db, {Props}=Doc, Atts, Options) ->
```

The stacktrace stating no function clause found:

```
 ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :couchbeam.save_doc/4
 stacktrace:
   (couchbeam) src/couchbeam.erl:560: :couchbeam.save_doc({:db, {:server, "http://localhost:5984", [basic_auth: {"admin", "admin"}]}, "database", [basic_auth: {"admin", "admin"}]}, [_id: "auth_hello", content: 'some text'], [], [])
   (cs) lib/models/Auth.ex:60: anonymous fn/3 in Server.Model.Auth.signup/3
   test/model/auth_test.exs:7
```

Does save_doc/2 require something that the arguments passed in are missing?

Comment: For versions, my machine is running Elixir 1.0.5, Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.0] and CouchBeam 1.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

`doc = {[
      { "_id", "auth_#{username}" },
      { "content", "some text" }
    ]}`

The type `doc()` is defined as `{[{ejson_key(), ejson_term()}]}` in Erlang. The keyword list literal syntax you were using needed to be wrapped in a tuple.